# Angular Firebase hiding navbar at login screen

Tags: angular2-routing, navbar, angularfire2

Can someone help me understand the best way to hide the navbar on this login screen while I'm not logged in.  once I login it is persistent for my app(for some reason my logins are not working in stackblitz, but it works fine on my localhost). my navbar is generated from `app.component.html` and then upon successful login `routes` calls `dashboard.component.html`.  i neeed to hide navbar on the login screen... and if anyone knows why my google, twitter, and email auth are not working on Snackblitz, that would help...it's a great platform for helping understand coding.  Thanks for any help!

All the code is here on this StackBlitz.

[Hiding navbar on the login screen](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hiding-navbar-after-login?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: `ng-if="!authenticated` or something like that? when it is true, hide the navbar since user has not yet logged in

Comment: ok i tried this.  I have a variable 'LOGGEDIN' set to true/false.  I have '<div *ngIf="LOGGEDIN"> ... all my navbar code here... </div>' in my app.component.html and it DOES hide the menu at login screen, but then when I login and my routes navigates to dashboard... the navbar is still hidden ... what to I need to do after login to get the navbar to show?

Comment: on login page you set `LOGGEDIN` to `false` and after logging in you set `LOGGEDIN` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

use *ngIf=!authenticate(this will be true only if user is logged in)